# Querying LDAP using expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, ldap, expression-trees

I develop an application connecting LDAP. In .NET framework there's a namespace System.DirectoryServices.Protocols with set of classes dedicated to handle LDAP queries.

Basically there are two classes:

- SearchRequest
- SearchResponse

To query LDAP SearchRequest requires following arguments:

- string distinguishedName
- string ldapFilter
- SearchScope searchScope
- params string[] attributeList

The thing I don't like about this approach is ldapFilter parameter. It requires query in LDAP format (for instance `(|(sn=SomeSurname)(givenName=SomeFirstname)`). My idea is to create some mapping to allow developers to query LDAP in a convenient way, namely using LINQ.

I want to create following method:

```
List<User> GetByFilter(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter)
```

POCO User represents LDAP user and filter allow to query LDAP using LINQ in a .NET manner.

The problem is that mapping between expression tree and LDAP query is a complex issue. I've done some research on the Internet, but I haven't found anything. Does anyone know if there's any mapper for this? Is there any .NET library or maybe Entity/nHibernate driver to do this?

Comment: I've never used it myself (I'm too fond of the lovely LDAP filters syntax, I'm afraid), but there is a Linq to LDAP library at https://linqtoldap.codeplex.com/. There are also several other questions about it on SO.

Comment: Here is a nice resource for Linq providers: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/10/05/links-to-linq.aspx